# CSS Sprite fade animation

Tags: css, css-transitions, fadein, css-animations, sprite

I basically need to make the sprite elements have a fade animation instead of the scrolling effect (an opacity animation instead of background-position). How can i do that with css3 or with js, but without jquery? And is there a way to position the elements not with pixels, but with % or rems (in the code below)?

```
.youtube {
    background-position: -256px -256px;
    &:hover {
        background-position: -256px -384px;
    }
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zvj89o0o/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### background-position: x% y%;

Actually, the percent background-position works like this:

- When **abscissa** is `0%`, then image's left side aligns container's left side.
- When **abscissa** is `100%`, then image's right side aligns with container's right side.
- Intermediate values are calculated linearly.

Similarly,

- When **ordinate** is `0%`, then image's top side aligns container's top side.
- When **ordinate** is `100%`, then image's bottom side aligns with container's bottom.
- Intermediate values are calculated linearly.

---

### Your question

In your question, there could be **3 desirable values** for abscissa of sprite container : `0%`, `50%`, and `100%`, and there could be **4 desirable values** for ordinate : `0%`, `33.33%`, `66.66%`, and `100%`. See the following figure:
[image]

For adding fading effect, add a pseudo-element `:before` above the normal elements. Now, position the background accordingly and add hover effects for fading.

### Updated Snippet:

```css
body {
  background: #141414;
}
.sprites {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
.youtube,
.pinterest,
.vk,
.facebook,
.twitter,
.instagram {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/xGT3jFF.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.youtube:before,
.pinterest:before,
.vk:before,
.facebook:before,
.twitter:before,
.instagram:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  content: "";
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/xGT3jFF.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.youtube {
  background-position: 100% 100%;
}
.youtube:before {
  background-position: 100% 66.6666%;
}
.youtube:hover:before {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}
.pinterest {
  background-position: 50% 100%;
}
.pinterest:before {
  background-position: 50% 66.6666%;
}
.pinterest:hover:before {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}
.vk {
  background-position: 0% 100%;
}
.vk:before {
  background-position: 0px 66.6666%;
}
.vk:hover:before {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}
.facebook {
  background-position: 100% 33.333%;
}
.facebook:before {
  background-position: 100% 0%;
}
.facebook:hover:before {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}
.twitter {
  background-position: 50% 33.3333%;
}
.twitter:before {
  background-position: 50% 0%;
}
.twitter:hover:before {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}
.instagram {
  background-position: 0% 33.33333%;
}
.instagram:before {
  background-position: 0% 0%;
}
.instagram:hover:before {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="sprites">
  <a class="instagram" href="http://instagram.com"></a>
  <a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com"></a>
  <a class="facebook" href="https://fb.com"></a>
  <a class="vk" href="https://vk.com"></a>
  <a class="pinterest" href="https://pinterest.com"></a>
  <a class="youtube" href="https://youtube.com"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.youtube {
    background-position: -256px -256px;
    transition-property:opacity;
    transition-duration:0.5s;
    opacity:1;
    &:hover {
        background-position: -256px -384px;
        opacity:0.5;
    }
}
```

Note the new properties I added

Comment: Well, the animation doesn't look good) Actually, this is a problem to make it fade normally without jumping between layers